# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET azure container instance

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, jaeger

I need to host jaeger in azure container instance and currently host is running in azure container instance but when i go to Ip address in browser it shows Error connection reset same result in DNS also. Im using jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest as image while creating container instance

[image: Jaeger Azure container instance]

Comment: Could you include more details like error screenshots and config details?

Comment: updated question with image of azure container instance. Container is running but when i go to site address it show Err_Connection_reset also tried with address:16686 port not working, Its working in local environment

Comment: Can you please check the NSG rules that you have added or not you are getting this error because of There is no Allow inbound rules from Internet to LoadBalancer
Could you please create appropriate NSG rules to allow inbound rules from Internet